# Proto-Buf.Net and serialization

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, protobuf-net, patricia-trie

I've a problem with serializing an object using protobuf.net. I've used it on other classes and it works very well, but using this it doesn't.

Could you help me saying why. Thanks.

I want to use protobuf because BinaryFormatter is very slow in serializing/deserializing.

This is the class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using ProtoBuf;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace RadixTree
{
[Serializable, DataContract, ProtoContract]
public class Node<T>
{
    private readonly List<Node<T>> children = new List<Node<T>>();
    private readonly string key;
    private T value;
    public Node(string key, T value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    private Node()
    {
    }
    protected bool HasChildren
    {
        get { return children.Count > 0; }
    }
    public void Insert(string key, T value)
    {
        var potentialChild = new Node<T>(key, value);
        Add(potentialChild);
    }
    private bool Add(Node<T> theNewChild)
    {
        if (Contains(theNewChild))
            throw new DuplicateKeyException(string.Format("Duplicate key: '{0}'", theNewChild.key));

        if (!IsParentOf(theNewChild))
            return false;

        bool childrenObligedRequest = RequestChildrenToOwn(theNewChild);
        if (childrenObligedRequest) return true;

        AcceptAsOwnChild(theNewChild);
        return true;
    }
    private bool RequestChildrenToOwn(Node<T> newChild)
    {
        return
            children.Exists(
                existingChild =>
                existingChild.MergeIfSameAs(newChild) || existingChild.Add(newChild) ||
                ForkANewChildAndAddChildren(existingChild, newChild));
    }
    private bool MergeIfSameAs(Node<T> potentialChild)
    {
        if (!IsTheSameAs(potentialChild) || IsNotUnrealNode())
            return false;

        value = potentialChild.value;
        return true;
    }
    private bool IsNotUnrealNode()
    {
        return !IsUnrealNode();
    }
    private void Disown(Node<T> existingChild)
    {
        children.Remove(existingChild);
    }
    private Node<T> AcceptAsOwnChild(Node<T> child)
    {
        if (NotItself(child)) children.Add(child);
        return this;
    }
    private bool NotItself(Node<T> child)
    {
        return !Equals(child);
    }
    private bool ForkANewChildAndAddChildren(Node<T> existingChild, Node<T> newChild)
    {
        if (existingChild.IsNotMySibling(newChild))
            return false;

        var surrogateParent = MakeASurrogateParent(existingChild, newChild);
        if (surrogateParent.IsTheSameAs(this))
            return false;

        SwapChildren(existingChild, newChild, surrogateParent);
        return true;
    }
    private bool IsNotMySibling(Node<T> newChild)
    {
        return !IsMySibling(newChild);
    }
    private void SwapChildren(Node<T> existingChild, Node<T> newChild, Node<T> surrogateParent)
    {
        surrogateParent.AcceptAsOwnChild(existingChild)
            .AcceptAsOwnChild(newChild);

        AcceptAsOwnChild(surrogateParent);
        Disown(existingChild);
    }
    private Node<T> MakeASurrogateParent(Node<T> existingChild, Node<T> newChild)
    {
        string keyForNewParent = existingChild.CommonBeginningInKeys(newChild);
        keyForNewParent = keyForNewParent.Trim();
        var surrogateParent = new Node<T>(keyForNewParent, default(T));

        return surrogateParent.IsTheSameAs(newChild) ? newChild : surrogateParent;
    }
    private bool IsTheSameAs(Node<T> parent)
    {
        return Equals(parent);
    }
    private bool IsMySibling(Node<T> potentialSibling)
    {
        return CommonBeginningInKeys(potentialSibling).Length > 0;
    }
    private string CommonBeginningInKeys(Node<T> potentialSibling)
    {
        return key.CommonBeginningWith(potentialSibling.key);
    }
    internal virtual bool IsParentOf(Node<T> potentialChild)
    {
        return potentialChild.key.StartsWith(key);
    }
    public bool Delete(string key)
    {
        Node<T> nodeToBeDeleted = children.Find(child => child.Find(key) != null);
        if (nodeToBeDeleted == null) return false;

        if (nodeToBeDeleted.HasChildren)
        {
            nodeToBeDeleted.MarkAsUnreal();
            return true;
        }

        children.Remove(nodeToBeDeleted);
        return true;
    }
    private void MarkAsUnreal()
    {
        value = default(T);
    }
    public T Find(string key)
    {
        var childBeingSearchedFor = new Node<T>(key, default(T));
        return Find(childBeingSearchedFor);
    }
    private T Find(Node<T> childBeingSearchedFor)
    {
        if (Equals(childBeingSearchedFor)) return value;
        T node = default(T);
        children.Find(child =>
                          {
                              node = child.Find(childBeingSearchedFor);
                              return node != null;
                          });
        if (node == null) return default(T);
        return node;
    }
    public bool Contains(string key)
    {
        return Contains(new Node<T>(key, default(T)));
    }
    private bool Contains(Node<T> child)
    {
        if (Equals(child) && IsUnrealNode()) return false;

        if (Equals(child)) return true;

        return children.Exists(node => node.Contains(child));
    }
    private bool IsUnrealNode()
    {
        return value == null;
    }
    public List<T> Search(string keyPrefix)
    {
        var nodeBeingSearchedFor = new Node<T>(keyPrefix, default(T));
        return Search(nodeBeingSearchedFor);
    }
    private List<T> Search(Node<T> nodeBeingSearchedFor)
    {
        if (IsTheSameAs(nodeBeingSearchedFor))
            return MeAndMyDescendants();

        return SearchInMyChildren(nodeBeingSearchedFor);
    }
    private List<T> SearchInMyChildren(Node<T> nodeBeingSearchedFor)
    {
        List<T> searchResults = null;

        children.Exists(existingChild => (searchResults = existingChild.SearchUpAndDown(nodeBeingSearchedFor)).Count > 0);

        return searchResults;
    }
    private List<T> SearchUpAndDown(Node<T> node)
    {
        if (node.IsParentOf(this))
            return MeAndMyDescendants();

        return IsParentOf(node) ? Search(node) : new List<T>();

    }
    private List<T> MeAndMyDescendants()
    {
        var meAndMyDescendants = new List<T>();
        if (!IsUnrealNode())
            meAndMyDescendants.Add(value);

        children.ForEach(child => meAndMyDescendants.AddRange(child.MeAndMyDescendants()));
        return meAndMyDescendants;
    }
    public long Size()
    {
        const long size = 0;
        return Size(size);
    }
    private long Size(long size)
    {
        if (!IsUnrealNode())
            size++;

        children.ForEach(node => size += node.Size());
        return size;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return key;
    }
    public bool Equals(Node<T> other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Equals(other.key, key);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (Node<T>)) return false;
        return Equals((Node<T>) obj);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (key != null ? key.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
    public static Node<T> Root()
    {
        return new RootNode<T>();
    }
    public List<Node<T>> getChildren()
    {
        return children;
    }
    [Serializable, DataContract, ProtoContract]
    private class RootNode<T> : Node<T>
    {
        public RootNode() { }
        internal override bool IsParentOf(Node<T> potentialChild)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because protobuf-net, along with things like `DataContractSerializer` and `XmlSerializer` etc, does not simply work on fields. It needs *information* about which fields to serialize and how to identify them (although there *is* an implicit option, I try not to recommend it). For example:

```
[ProtoMember(3)] private readonly List<Node<T>> children = new List<Node<T>>();
[ProtoMember(1)] private readonly string key;
[ProtoMember(2)] private T value;
```

Which should then work fine.

(there are other ways of indicating which members to serialize - the attributes are just the most convenient; for info, the same would work with `[DataMember(Order=n)]`, since your type is also marked as a `[DataContract]`)

---

The following works fine for me:

```
[Test]
public void Main()
{
    Node<int> tree = new Node<int>("abc", 1), clone;
    var children = tree.getChildren();
    children.Add(new Node<int>("abc/def", 2));
    children.Add(new Node<int>("abc/ghi", 3));
    Assert.AreEqual(2, tree.getChildren().Count);

    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, tree);
        Assert.Greater(1, 0); // I always get these args the wrong way around, 
        Assert.Greater(ms.Length, 0); // so I always double-check!
        ms.Position = 0;
        clone = Serializer.Deserialize<Node<int>>(ms);
    }

    Assert.AreEqual("abc", clone.Key);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, clone.Value);
    children = clone.getChildren();
    Assert.AreEqual(2, children.Count);

    Assert.IsFalse(children[0].HasChildren);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc/def", children[0].Key);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, children[0].Value);

    Assert.IsFalse(children[1].HasChildren);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc/ghi", children[1].Key);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, children[1].Value);
}
```

---

Edit following project example:

Firstly, note that `RootNode<T>` should actually be just `RootNode` - a nested type already inherits the `T` from the containing type.

There are two issues here:

First, there's the issue of `RootNode` - you were right that this relationship would need to be declared, but the C# compiler has no love for generics in attributes. Frankly, I would say *encapsulate* the root rather than inherit. If you must inherit, it is a pain, and you would have to declare it at runtime, i.e.

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Node<MyDto>), true)
     .AddSubType(4, typeof(Node<MyDto>.RootNode));
```

The second issue is nested lists/arrays; `children` would be a `List<List<YourType>>`. At the current time, that scenario *is not supported*, although I am a bit confused why it didn't raise an exception - it is *meant* to throw a `NotSupportedException` citing:

> Nested or jagged lists and arrays are not supported

I will investigate why it didn't raise that!

The problem here is that the protobuf spec (outside my control) has no way of representing such data unless there is a message in the middle, i.e.

```
[ProtoContract]
class SomeNewType {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<MyDto> Items {get {return items;}}
    private readonly List<MyDto> items = new List<MyDto>();
}
```

and use `Node<SomeNewType>` rather than `Node<List<MyDto>>`.

*In theory*, protobuf-net could *pretend* that layer was in the middle, and just carry on anyway - but simply: I haven't had time to design/write/test the code required to do that yet.

Comment: Hi I've tried to use ProtoMember but it doesn't work. I don't know what to do. I want to use protobuf because BinaryFormatter is too slow. Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: I've also trie to add DataMember but it doesn't work. Could you say me how to use the implicit option?

Comment: I've also used this code: [ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields)]. No results. Filesize is always 0kb!! :(

Comment: @Mapo I have a test based on the same issue you raised on google-code - it works fine. Two moments...

Comment: @Mapo test added. Do you have a concrete example that **doesn't** work, or that writes zero bytes? Note I added some accessors (or made them public) simply so I could test the values afterwards; that doesn't affect the serialization - just the ability to verify the data.

Comment: One moment and I'll give you a test project!

Comment: @Mapo preferably minimal... i.e. the least that is required to illustrate the problem...

Comment: Hi, you can find a simple sample project here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9955238/TestProject.zip

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. I've made some of changes you have suggested but I don't understand "I would say encapsulate the root rather than inherit". How to do it? Could you help me?

Comment: @Mapo sorry, I didn't see your two comments. I gave an encapsulation example in my answer of using. I'll add something else too - 1 moment...

Comment: @Mapo here we go; 4 integration test: 1 simple value (`Int32`), one complex-type but single instance, one *list*-of-complex-type (should error, this test needs work), and one with an encapsulation layer (see  `TestSomeNewType`). http://protobuf-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Examples/Issues/Issue297.cs - also, don't forget to see the code in the `Init()` method that configures the inheritance

Comment: @Mapo I should also note that a more pragmatic way might be to use a dedicated DTO rather than trying to torture your domain model

Comment: Hi!! You are my life save. I figured out what was wrong!! Thanks very very much!!!